# iframe размер контейнера адаптируется под контент фрейма (inline стиль/скрипт)

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Есть `iframe` на лендинге. Во фрейме запись на мероприятие из 3-х шагов. Каждый шаг различной высоты.

Какой стиль прописать во фрейме (только инлайн в моем случае), чтобы фрейм менял высоту на лендинге на каждом этапе, не появлялся скролл там, где контент не влезает?

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял то так, должно работать.

```
<iframe src="/" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="auto">
```

Comment: Не подходит. было 650px в высоту, так хотя видно было что-то. С авто, блок сжимается до нельзя. То есть auto не подойдет.